# SQL if @name exists select ID else insert @name into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE names
(ID int,
 name varchar(10) unique)
```

I need to achieve the following result:

```
if @name not exists in names then insert into names (name) values (@name)
select id from names where name=@name
```

It would be best to achieve it with user defined function.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Then do that. This is not a development vending machine...Put in requirement get code...

Comment: How do i get one of those ??? are they free

Comment: I am asking how i can achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have the answer written in your question already:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM names WHERE name = @name))
    INSERT INTO names (name) values (@name);

SELECT id FROM names WHERE name = @name;
```

The only problem is that you haven't set up your table `names` to use an `IDENTITY` column. This means you need to assign values for `id` as well.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Is it possible to do it with user defined function which returns selected id?

Comment: @Martin Smith - Saw your comment after writing a mock myself. You're right. You can't insert from a function. OP probably will need to use a stored procedure if he wants to encapsulate `INSERT` logic.